# Need the window close button to clear a text box - XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml

When the window opens up, there is a blank text box. The options are "Ok", "Cancel" and the x button on upper right of the window title bar. If you type in text in the textbox and hit cancel, the window closes and upon opening the window again, the text is gone, as it should be. "Ok" has its own behavior. But, when you type in text and hit the x button to close the window and open it back up, the text is still there. I need this x button to have the same behavior as the cancel button, which is to close the window and clear the text. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **Closing event** to the window where the textbox is, then, inside that event, indicate the textbox to clear.

An example would be this:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Clear();
    }
```

I'll add to you this documentation of how to add this event in your xaml and cs: [Window.Closing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: I use a string to keep track of the text in the text box. When cancel is pressed, that string is set to empty. The code you gave would go in the xaml.cs file and I would have no way to access that string as it is in the model.cs file. Also the textbox was created in xaml so there is no way to directly access it from c#.

Comment: @user19352673 Could you add the code of your Cancel button?